# golang undefined: Scanner

Tags: go

Golang has scanner interface which you can also take an example from this file https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/database/sql/convert.go

LINE: 377

```
if scanner, ok := dest.(Scanner); ok {
    return scanner.Scan(src)
}
```

But when i try to include the scanner interface in my code it gives error **"Undefined Scanner"** even i tried to import go/scanner etc. still no luck

Example what i am doing

```
var b interface{}

if scanner, ok := b.(Scanner); ok {
    fmt.Println("Scanner found")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As icza pointed out, `Scanner` is part of the sql package and the main package has no concept of a `Scanner` type. To make this code work you will need to do 2 things:

1. Add `import "database/sql"` to the top of the file
2. Change `b.(Scanner)` to `b.(sql.Scanner)` as you need to tell go where the Scanner type is defined.

Comment: Well spotted @icza, I've corrected the answer.